# Provide strong parameters in controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm looking to write a unit test for one of the methods of a controller which is as follows:

```
def update
  @key = current_user.keys.find_by_key(params[:id])
  @key.update_attributes(key_params)
  redirect_to :back
end

private

def key_params
  params.require(:key).permit(:note)
end
```

the route for this is:

```
PUT              /projects/:project_id/keys/:id           keys#update
```

So far I have the following:

```
describe '#update' do
  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @project= FactoryGirl.create(:project, user: @user)
    @key = FactoryGirl.create(:key, id: 40, project: @project, user: @user)
    controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user)
  end

  it 'update key' do
    put :update, project_id:@project.id, id:@key.id
    expect(response.code).to eq "302"
  end
end
```

But this gives an error as follows:

```
KeysController#update update key
 Failure/Error: put :update, project_id:@project.id, id:@key.id
 ActionController::ParameterMissing:
   param is missing or the value is empty: key
```

Any leads would be very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass key params to the action. And it is good idea to check not only response status, but action result too

```
it 'updates key' do
  # supposing that "note" is a string column
  expect do
    put :update, project_id: @project.id, id: @key.id, key: { note: 'New note' } 
  end.to change { @key.note }.from('Old note').to('New note')
  expect(response.code).to eq "302"
end
```

UPDATE:

In the controller you're trying to find key instance by key attribute

```
@key = current_user.keys.find_by_key(params[:id])
```

but you're passing key.id in specs. How it works in the app? I suppose, you pass a key as `:id` parameter, so it should be

```
put :update, project_id: @project.id, id: @key.key, key: { note: 'New note' }
```

in your specs. Also, `find_by_key` doesn't raise error if it can't find anything, it just returns nil. It means that you'll not get RecordNotFound. Moreover, it is a deprecated method, you should use `find_by(key: params[:id])` To raise error use bang method `find_by!(key: params[:id])`

If you're passing `key.id` in the app you need to make changes in the controller action

```
@key = current_user.keys.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: I got the following error when i followed what you suggested:
Failure/Error: put :update, params: {
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"keys", :params=>{:project_id=>"306", :id=>"50", :key=>{:note=>"New note"}}}

Comment: @aria, which rails version do you use?

Comment: Try `put :update, project_id: @project.id, id: @key.id, key: { note: 'New note' }`, without `params` key

Comment: I'm using rails version 4.1.16. @vasilisa

Comment: I tried the put request you mentioned and got the following error:
 Failure/Error: put :update, id: @key.id, project_id: @project.id, key: { note: 'New note' }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @aria, it is better :) It means that `@key = current_user.keys.find_by_key(params[:id])` returns nil in controller. Why you're finding by key, not with `current_user.keys.find(params[:id])`? What is 'key' attribute in Key model?

Comment: key here is like an API key which is a string and looks something like "0AFHYO7FAB5K1765"

Comment: @aria in this case you need to pass key as parameter or find by id

Comment: I tried passing key as parameter:
`put :update, id: @key.id, project_id: @project.id, key: { key: @key.key, note: 'New note' }`
Also tried  `put :update, id: @key.id, project_id: @project.id, key: @key.key, key: { note: 'New note' }`
both gave the same error "undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: @aria, I updated the answer, hope it helps you to understand